# Javascript I have a nested for loop in a while loop and it's not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why my code is going infinitely.

```
 var stateArray = ["CO", "AK", "CA", "KY", "NM"];
    var selectedStates = [];
    var important = 6
    while (important < 9)  {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedStates.length;i++){
            if (stateArray[j] == selectedStates[i]){
                break;
            } else {
                selectedStates.push(stateArray[j]);
                console.log(selectedStates);
                important++
            }
        }
    }
```

If you could help me that would be amazing.

Comment: In your code `selectedStates.length` always zero. Technically not changing `important`'s value because it is never running `for` loop's block and that's why it is an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah `selectedStates.length` is always zero, your `else` never runs since its nested in the for loop.

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: I would like the selectedStates array to have 3 different states selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want if you want 3 random states selected

```js
var stateArray = ["CO", "AK", "CA", "KY", "NM"];
var selectedStates = [];
var important = 6
while (important < 9) {
  let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  selectedStates.push(stateArray[j]);
  ++important;
}

console.log(selectedStates)
```

Or if you don't want duplicates then

```
 var stateArray = ["CO", "AK", "CA", "KY", "NM"];
  var selectedStates = [];
  var important = 6
  while (important < 9) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    if (selectedStates.includes((stateArray[j]))) {
      continue;
    }
    selectedStates.push(stateArray[j]);
    ++important;
  }

  console.log(selectedStates)
```

Answer (score 0):

What it seems is:

You're in the rounds of while loop.

you didn’t push anything in the `selectedStates` array yet, so how this for loop statement can be true `i < selectedStates.length` when `i` is already assigned `0`, and length of `selectedStates` is `0` as well.

and this while loop statement `important < 9` is always true because it's not getting increased from `6`.